# While on VPN, how do I use my fast internet connection for files not on the VPN?

Tags: macos, networking, vpn

When I connect to a VPN, I notice all my internet access slows to a crawl.  From ~5MB/sec to ~250KB/sec.

I'm using Cisco AnyConnect on OSX, which doesn't appear to have any basic options to say "don't use VPN for internet connections".

What do I need to know to make my laptop use my internet connection for the internet and the VPN for the VPN?

Comment: Talk to your VPN administrator. They have made this decision deliberately, and they may be doing so for a very important reason.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the VPN configuration.

Some configurations do not allow the client to route requests outside of it.

If your VPN configuration allows it you can modify the route table yourself and set your internet gateway as the default route and add specific rules (routes) for the IP segments you need to access through the VPN.

I had a similar situation but the VPN was configured to not allow other routes, so instead I used VMWare Fusion and ran a small WinXP box where I used the VPN connection. (VirtualBox would work too)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that while split tunneling allows for easy access to both secured and unsecured traffic, the disadvantage lies in the fact that since the secured gateways of the VPN are bypassed for accessing unsecured data, there is a danger of opening the door to unauthorized access to the secured network.

Regarding your question, Cisco AnyConnect prevents a split tunnel by temporarily re-writing the routing table of the host computer. Use `route print` before you start AnyConnect and use it again after to see the differences. You can write a script to adjust the routing table and run it after you start AnyConnect. An alternative solution that probably doesn't violate your networks usage policy is simply using a VM with AnyConnect. Your host's NIC doesn't get locked down.